# How to send message to phone# outside of the US?

Tags: vonage

My Nodejs app uses `nexmo 2.8.0` to send message to cell phones and it works fine with US phone number. My question is how to send the message to phone# of other countries such as China and Hong Kong? According to the `nexmo` doc, it shall work with international phone#. But I tried and the other party didn't receive it. Here is the code:

```
const Nexmo = require("nexmo");
const nexmo = new Nexmo({
                apiKey: process.env.nexmoApiKey,
                apiSecret: process.env.nexmoApiSecret
                }, { debug: true });        

function sendNexmoSms(nexmo, vcode, cell, cell_country_code){ //vcode is the message

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      nexmo.message.sendSms(process.env.nexmo_sender_number, cell_country_code + cell, vcode, {type: 'unicode'}, async (err, result) => {
           if(err){
             resolve('failed to send');   
           }else{
            if (result.messages[0]['status'] === "0") {
                resolve('success');         
              } else {
                resolve('failed to send');
              }
                       
          }              
       });
     });
};
```

Comment: Firstly, please use the newer SDK - info here: https://github.com/vonage/vonage-node-sdk
Secondly, please make sure the phone number is in the E164 format - don't use a leading + or 00 but start with the country code, for example 447700900000.

Comment: `Paul Ardeleanu`, what is the difference between nexmo and node-sdk? I checked npm and nexmo has many more downloads than node-sdk. Is node-sdk going to supersede nexmo?

Comment: FYI 447700900000 here 44 prefix is the country code for the UK

Comment: @user938363 Nexmo was a business that got acquired by Vonage (https://www.streetinsider.com/Corporate+News/Vonage+%28VG%29+Announces+Completion+of+%7E%24250M+Nexmo+Acquisition/11710835.html). The Node SDK was initially referred to as the Nexmo Node SDK and got superseded by the Vonage Node SDK: https://github.com/vonage/vonage-node-sdk

Answer (score 2):

According to [Vonage document](https://developer.vonage.com/api/sms), you should set the receiver number in E.164 format
Here is how to build E.164 format phone number: https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164

Comment: Hi `Tony Yip`, does E.164 require + before country code? `Paul Ardeleanu` says don't use + for E.164 format. I checked the E.164 document which requires + in front of country code. Currently I am not using + in front of country code.

Comment: @user938363 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164. The plus is not part of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more details about the question? It is not clear about the error code that you receive.

One of the issue can be routing issue as well.

Comment: There is no error code. The message seemed sent but was not received.